# Is it possible to use If Else statement in an Array?

Tags: java, arrays, function, loops, methods

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Arrays2 {

  public static void main(String[] args){
    int [] array = {1,2,10,20};

    addUp(array);
    showUp(array);
  }

  public static void addUp(int x[]){
    System.out.println("AddUp Function");
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
      System.out.print(x[i]+"\t");
    }
    System.out.println ("\n");

  }

  public static void showUp(int y[]){
    System.out.println("ShowUp Function which Multiplies by 2!");
    **If(array[] >= 10)**
    for (int k = 0; k < y.length; k++){
      System.out.print(y[k]*2+"\t");
    }
  } 
}
```

How can I apply an if-else statement in an array?
In my showUp method it should multiply the elements in the array if the value is greater than 10.

Comment: Please format your code. You don't apply `if-else` in an array.

Comment: Which value? Do you mean, for all the value in array that is greater than `10`, multiply it by `2`?

Comment: `If(array[] >= 10)` - doesn't seem like Java.

Comment: @Rohit Jain the value of my array {1, 2, 10, 20}; i want in the showUp method to multiply the arrays value whenever the value is greater than 10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
for (int k = 0; k < y.length; k++) {
    if (y[k] >= 10) {
        System.out.print(y[k] * 2 + "\t");
    }
}
```

What you wrote looks similar to a `filter` in some other programming languages, <strike>but Java does not have those</strike>. You have to iterate the array and use an `if` check *inside* the loop.

---

Update: Since Java 8, Java *does* have `Stream.filter`:

```
int[] array = {1, 2, 10, 20};
IntStream.of(array)
        .filter(x -> x >= 10)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: @togias_k THIS SHOULD DO IT!! THANKS!! it worked! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

This snippet wouldn't even compile:

```
public static void showUp(int y[]){
    System.out.println("ShowUp Function which Multiplies by 2!");
    If(array[] >= 10)
        for (int k = 0; k < y.length; k++){
            System.out.print(y[k]*2+"\t");
        }
}
```

First, `if` in Java is lowercase, and Java is case-sensitive. Second, there's no `array` variable in the `showUp` method. Third, `array[]` is invalid syntax.

Are you trying to check the length of your array `y` - the method parameter? Then you need to do this:

```
public static void showUp(int y[]){
    System.out.println("ShowUp Function which Multiplies by 2!");
    if (y.length >= 10)
        for (int k = 0; k < y.length; k++){
            System.out.print(y[k]*2+"\t");
        }
}
```

On second thoughts, the length can't be greater than 10, so please check the answer by @tobias_k - he seems to be right.

Comment: I think he means "if the content of the cell is greater then 10" not "if the length of the array is greater then 10"

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. Edited the answer. I'll keep it for my comments on why it wouldn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do this?

```
if(arr[i] > 10 )
{
    arr[i]=arr[i]*2;
}
you can do this
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use .length

```
public static void showUp(int y[]){
    System.out.println("ShowUp Function which Multiplies by 2!");
    if (y.length >= 10)
        for (int k = 0; k < y.length; k++){
            System.out.print(y[k]*2+"\t");
        }
}
```